# cakephp - mssql connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cakephp

I have to connect cakephp with mssql server. I have installed mssql in my system. how to specify the connection string?

I tried this:

```
 public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

But getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to escape the backslash; `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS`. Otherwise, try to use a 'port' in stead of a named instance: `'localhost,1433'` or `'localhost:1433'`